# Create UML diagrams with usages in PhpStorm 2016.3

Tags: php, uml, phpstorm

The following diagram shows the basic inheritance structure:

[image]

It happens that `ArrayOnlyUrlMaker` has instance variables of some other types, and I would like to add these relations to the diagram, so that it will be obvious that `ArrayOnlyUrlMaker` uses some other classes called `ConfigFetcher` and `QueryStringBuilder`. Also, there probably should be an option to provide a depth parameter to stop looking for inner usages after a certain level.

Is that possible with PhpStorm to display a "uses" relation in addition to "extends" or "implements"?

Answer (score 1):

I wish they had this feature, but unfortunately, they don't. The best tool so far to do the job would be Sparx Enterprise Architect (Commercial) or [PHUML](https://github.com/jakobwesthoff/phuml).